# Problem with Visual Studio macro to remove a project from a solution

Tags: visual-studio, macros

I have recorded a macro with me selecting a project and removing it from the solution, resulting in this code:

```
DTE.ActiveWindow.Object.GetItem("PerfixEMS\Allocations\BDAUploader\perFIXAllocationsFTP").Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect)
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Delete")
```

This macro works nicely if the project is in the solution, but causes a runtime error if it has already been removed.  Even assigning the result if `GetItem` to an `Object` variable, to check for Nothing before calling `Select`, causes a runtime error.  How can I error proof this macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put that in a `Try` block:

```
Try
    DTE.ActiveWindow.Object.GetItem("PerfixEMS\Allocations\BDAUploader\perFIXAllocationsFTP").Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect)
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Delete")
Catch
End Try
```

**Update:** I think your macro is not very safe.  It uses active window and that window could be any window.  I suggest something like this:

```
Try
    DTE.Solution.Remove(DTE.Solution.Projects.Item("test.vcproj"))
Catch
End Try
```

Project is referenced by its `UniqueName` property here.  That name is projects path relative to the solution and its file extension.  You can explore the properties by running a macro under the macro debugger.  Projects can also be referenced by their 1-based index (`DTE.Solution.Projects.Item(1)`).